# Android NavigationView prevent selecting item, setCheckedItem not working inside onNavigationItemSelected

Tags: android, android-navigationview

This is the code in `onNavigationItemSelected`

```
  R.id.nav_subscribed -> {
        if (prefs.getLong("userid", 0L) == 0L) {
            when (currentGal) {
                "top" -> {
                    // navView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_top)
                    // navView.menu.getItem(R.id.nav_top).isChecked = true
                }
            }

            val i = Intent(this, Login::class.java)
            this.startActivity(i)
        } else {
            if(currentGal != "subscriptions"){
                getMemes("subscriptions", 0)
            }
        }
    }
```

I try to prevent `nav_subscribed` to be checked when the user isn't logged in and check/keep checked `nav_top`

```
navView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_top)
```

isn't working and

`navView.menu.getItem(R.id.nav_top).isChecked = true`

crashed the app. So how to do this? Btw android is awful broken garbage software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     navigationView?.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    
                when (it.itemId) {
                    R.id.nav_subscribed -> { 
  //  if you don't want an item to be selected return false
         return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener false
                    }
                    R.id.nav_top -> {
                       
                    }
                
                 
                }
//return true to select the other items
                true
            }
```